# Django REST Multiple Nested Serializer Filter

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

Is there a  way to filter  multiple nested serializers?

I have a Student serializer that displays all of the students courses. The courses display all the homework and their scores. They way I want to design the backend is that every student will receive the same homework outline but only the scores change; so to reduce duplicate data I create the scores table that points to the homework and the student.

However, when I do a GET request it gets all of the students scores for that homework instance. Is there a way to filter it to only get a particular students score? I simplified my models for this example but the problem is essentially the same.

In my Response, you can see "score":1 and "score":2, these belong to two different students but I want to get the specific score that relates to the a particular Student.

**Models**

```
class Student(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=18)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstName


class Course(models.Model):
    courseName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    courseYear = models.IntegerField(default=2021)
    student = models.ManyToManyField(Student, related_name='courses')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.courseName + " " + str(self.courseYear)


class Homework(models.Model):
    hwName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    hwPossScore = models.IntegerField(default=100)
    course = models.ForeignKey(
        Course, related_name='homeworks', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.hwName


class Score(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(
        Student, related_name='studentScore', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    homework = models.ForeignKey(
        Homework, related_name='studentScore', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.student.firstName + " " + str(self.score)
```

**Serializers**

```
class ScoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Score
        fields = ['score', ]


class HomeworkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    studentScore = ScoreSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Homework
        fields = ['hwName', 'hwPossScore', 'studentScore', ]


class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    homeworks = HomeworkSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = "__all__"


class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    courses = CourseSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = "__all__"
```

**Views**

```
class StudentView(APIView):

    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, ]

    def get_object(self, request):
        try:
            requestToken = request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'].split(' ')[1]
            userObj = Token.objects.get(key=requestToken).user
            studentObj = Student.objects.filter(user=userObj)[0]

            # If requester token does not match user return permission denied
            if(self.request.user != userObj):
                raise PermissionDenied()

            return studentObj
        except Student.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, format=None):

        # Create a field variable for all Board objects that count the number of topics for each board
        student = self.get_object(request)
        serializer = StudentSerializer(student)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**Response**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "courses": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "homeworks": [
                {
                    "hwName": "HW1",
                    "hwPossScore": 100,
                    "studentScore": [
                        {
                            "score": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "score": 2
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "courseName": "MATH 101",
            "courseYear": 2021,
            "student": [
                1
            ]
        }
    ],
    "firstName": "Red",
    "age": 18
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use ScoreSerializer instead StudentSerializer. In ScoreSerializer, that class inheritance ModelSerializer you can use field = '**all**', because in ScoreModel has student, score, and homeworks field.

Comment: I think that will work but I would also like to know how to filter nested serializers. Like if I wanted all the homework for a student's specific course, I think if I go with the ScoreSerializer way I would only get one HW instance if I get by PK or if I decide to list then I would get all of the user's homework for all courses.